# How to install all missing Assemblies and Nuget packages with dependency in one go - Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I am trying to learn Microsoft Service Fabric and completely new to Visual Studio .

I am trying to follow some tutorial on creating a Service Fabric stateless endpoint . But many missing references are there.

I come to know there are two options -  Adding missing Assembly references and adding missing packages.

Using Nuget package manager console I tried adding one of the missing package but it failed as i didnt had the required dependency .

Is there any command or Visual studio option using that I can install all missing assembly  , packages and there dependency in one go ?

Problem here is I am new to  Microsoft tech stack and I am not aware of what reference requires which Assembly and respective packages with dependency .

[image]

Comment: Have u tried right click on solution and "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" / "Manage Nuget Packages for Project" ? Normaly nuget installs everything needed

Comment: @TobiasTheel , yes i tried that . But I am not sure which packages i should select from nuget repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like you are just missing the usings in your class.
Try to click on the red underlined Objects, a light bulb should appear. 
Click on that lightbulb and select "add using for xx" or similar.

If that is not available you are truly missing references.
And as i said if u are using resharper u select the red underlined objects hit alt+enter and select import missing reference / add missing using

Comment: I was able to add required packages after right clicking References and choosing Nuget Package manager . But when same thing I was trying after right clicking my Project I was getting errors . Why so and is this correct approach?

Comment: Can you provide the Errors itself? When i install a nuget packet the workflow is : Rightclick on Project -> Manage Package -> Chose a Package -> Install package - finish nothing more to do

Answer (score 1):

> Problem here is I am new to Microsoft tech stack and I am not aware of what reference requires which Assembly and respective packages with dependency .

Exactly, but the same problem is for Visual Studio, how could it know which nuget package would resolve the problem from the code? Some nuget packages would have the same commands, some of them even same namespaces. Actually Visual Studio cannot know for sure even if some particular nuget will work in your project until it tries to install it.

Comment: Anyplace on Microsoft site where I can find what package I should Install along with dependency for that particular assembly ?What should be the approach in general to handle this ?I know with experience its easy :)

Comment: What kind of assemblies are you talking about? .NET assemblies, or nuget packages? Maybe your only problem is a missing using in your class and not a missing reference? If that is the case : Resharper is your solution as it helps you add missing usings

Comment: @TobiasTheel I am gonna try Resharper . Please check Image for missing references

Comment: As you probably pick the code from some source, you probably have access to all files, and try to check all files, you should see required data in your .csproj file